# Can't PUT data to MEAN application

Tags: angular, undefined, mean, put

I can't update the categories for my MEAN application. When clicking the update button in my .html file I get the following error message: **Cannot read property '_id' of undefined** for my service.ts

This is my **component.html**:

```
<div class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories">
<form>
  <input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="category.name">
  <textarea name="description" [(ngModel)]="category.description"></textarea>
  <button (click)="updateCategory(category._id)">Update</button>
</form>
```

This is my **component.ts**:

```
updateCategory(_id){
    this.appService.updateCategory(this.category);    
  }
```

This is my **service.ts**:

```
updateCategory(category: Category){
let payload = {
  "id": category._id,
  "name": category.name,
  "description": category.description
}
console.log(category._id);
this.http.put(this.apiUrl+"/category/"+ category._id, payload, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(response => {});}
```

The database connection and API works fine. It's just that my values are undefined. My guess is that it has something to do with *ngFor making the data async, but I'm not sure. **How do I define _id, name and description in service.ts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the category used here being set?

```
updateCategory(_id){
    this.appService.updateCategory(this.category);       }
```

You are passing in an id to the updateCategory method, but then passing along `this.category`.

Where is the `this.category` being set?

It may make more sense to pass in the category instead of the id:

```
<button (click)="updateCategory(category)">Update</button>
```

And then:

```
updateCategory(category){
    this.appService.updateCategory(category);    
  }
```

Give that a try.